# forkしたHerokuリポジトリへpushできない

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3

herokuにpushすると成功するリポジトリがあります。
これをフォークします。

```
% heroku fork -a app app-staging
```

フォークしたリポジトリへpushします。

```
% git remote add staging git@heroku.com:app-staging.git 
% git push staging master --force   

Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 21260, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14754/14754), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21260/21260), 121.25 MiB | 381.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 21260 (delta 6604), reused 19575 (delta 5282)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Multipack app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
=====> Detected Framework: Ruby
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.7.12
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching source index from http://rubygems.org/
       Fetching git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git
       Net::HTTPNotFound: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not
       exist.</Message><Key>quick/Marshal.4.8/0.1.0.gemspec.rz</Key><RequestId>...</RequestId><HostId>...</HostId></Error>
       Bundler Output: Fetching source index from http://rubygems.org/
       Fetching git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git
       Net::HTTPNotFound: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not
       exist.</Message><Key>quick/Marshal.4.8/0.1.0.gemspec.rz</Key>    <RequestId>...</RequestId><HostId>...</HostId></Error>
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app

To git@heroku.com:app-staging.git
 ! [remote rejected] staging -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:app-staging.git'
```

様々なサイトを見てもこれでpushできると書いてあるのですがpushに失敗します。
原因は、使用しているAWS,S3,route53,buildpacksの内のどれかではないかと思うのですが、エラーメッセージで調べても分かりません、どうかご教示ください。ここまで読んでいただきありがとうございます。